# Area of shaded region (2 triangles)

Tags: triangles

> [image]

> Find the area of the shaded region.

I don't really have any idea how to do this. Is it possible to find the area or there is a lack of information to answer this question?

Comment: It's possible to find, relatively simply, the area of the shaded region using just the information which is provided.

Comment: Hint: can you find the areas of $ABF$ and $DBF$?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Magenta It's great that you've figured it out. As such, please consider answering this question yourself.

Comment: Oh I just know I can answer my own question. Ok I will answer it

Answer (score 2):

Area of ABF = 1/2 x 5 x 4 = 10

Area of DBF = 1/2 x 10 x 4 = 20

Area of CBF = 1/2 x 4 x 3 = 6

Area of shaded region = 10 + 20 - 2 x 6 = 18

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I have deleted my comment. Thank you.